# Android OS on old nokia phone

Tags: operating-system

Is it possible or has some one devised a way where we can update old nokia phone like nokia 6630 to android OS?

Answer (score 0):

Nokia 6630 runs on Symbian, which is a totally different OS to Android. You can't install Android on Symbian - It's like trying to watch TV with your dishwasher.